# Passing a list into MultipleChoiceField form as initial value

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a field called 'service'. It stores a list of ints that are representative of the services that a company offers (1=accounting, 2=HR, etc.). Once the list is saved to the 'service' field, I want to be able to pass it in as an 'initial' value to the form so that the user can see what options they previously selected.

**What works:**

a) User can select services

b) Services are saved to the 'service' field as a list of ints (eg. [2, 3, 5])

**What doesn't work:**

a) No initial values are shown within the form despite the fact that 'service' contains a list of ints.

model.py

```
class BaseServicesOffered(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    service = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

form.py

```
class BaseServicesOfferedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')  
        selectedservices = kwargs.pop('selectedservices')
        super(BaseServicesOfferedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['service'].choices = [(t.id, t.service) for t in AllServices.objects.filter(industrycode=user.userprofile.industry)]
        self.fields['service'].initial = selectedservices

    class Meta:  
        exclude = ('user',)
        model = BaseServicesOffered
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")    
def baseservicesoffered(request):

    try:
        base_services_offered = BaseServicesOffered.objects.create(user=request.user)

    except:
        pass

    user = request.user
    services = user.baseservicesoffered.service
    instance = get_object_or_404(BaseServicesOffered, user=user)
    form = BaseServicesOfferedForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user, selectedservices=services, instance=instance)    

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user

            service = form.cleaned_data['service']
            services = [int(i) for i in service] 
            instance.service = services

            instance.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/profile/')

        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'accounts/setup8.html', context)

    context = {'form': form}            
    return render(request, 'accounts/setup8.html', context)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

In your form `__init__` try to change

```
self.fields['service'].initial = selectedservices
```

to

```
self.initial['service'] = selectedservices
```

And make sure `selectedservices` is a list of ints (not a list of couples like `choices` and not a string with commas).

PS: If you storing your choices as strings instead of ints `initial` should be list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. Here is what you should do:

forms.py

```
class BaseServicesOfferedForm(forms.ModelForm):
service = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')  
    **selectedservices = kwargs.pop('selectedservices')**
    super(BaseServicesOfferedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['service'].choices = [(t.id, t.service) for t in AllServices.objects.filter(industrycode=user.userprofile.industry)]
    self.fields['service'].initial = selectedservices**

class Meta:  
    exclude = ('user',)
    model = BaseServicesOffered
```

Comment: Based on my research, I feel like this is the right answer, but it still doesn't work (i.e. initial values aren't being set in the form). I've updated my original question to include this code as I believe it is the most correct code that I have at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your code doesn't work is this:

In views.py:

```
services = user.baseservicesoffered.service
```

gives a *string* as the value of services, e.g. '[2, 3, 5]'. And then you pass services as selectedservices into your form:

```
form = BaseServicesOfferedForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user, selectedservices=services, instance=instance)
```

In your form, when you assign the value of selectedservices as the initial value of service:

```
self.fields['service'].initial = selectedservices
```

A string is being assigned to initial, but there is no item like '[2, 3, 5]'. What you want is each of the values 2, 3, 5 to be passed to initial.

Here:

```
services = [int(i) for i in service] 
instance.service = services
```

you are attempting to save a list into a CharField, which literally gets saved as '[2, 3, 5]' (you can check your database tables to be sure).

So either you must convert the string selectedservices back into a list in the form, somehow, or don't save the list into a CharField.

Comment: When I print(instance.service), it comes out as a list: [3, 4]. Even if I change  self.fields['service'].initial = selectedservices to self.fields['service'].initial = [2], the form still doesn't get rendered with id 2 checked off

Comment: @JasonHoward when you print instance.service it will come out as a list, because at the object level service is assigned a list as its value, and it will keep that, but when you save the instance, it is saved in the _database_ as a string. Try doing this: `BaseServicesOffered.objects.get(user=...).service` and you will see what I mean. Though I'm not sure why `self.fields['service'].initial = [2]` doesn't work. Let me think more on that.

Answer (score 0):

i was dealing with the same problem.
having a MultipleChoiceField form with a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget and saving the data as a CharField in the models.

the data was saved as literal strings that looks like a list but its not.
and the form is expecting a list for its initial values for the said field.

converting the strings to a python list did the trick like this below snippet in view.py

```
import ast

def land_demand_form(request):
    obj= get_object_or_404(Contact, user=request.user)
    res = ast.literal_eval(obj.prefered_contact)
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, initial={"prefered_contact": res})
    context= {'form': form}
```

check out this blog for more: [here](https://www.csestack.org/initialize-default-multiple-choice-field-django/)